# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord' Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I'm new to bot hosting and i got a error from heroku, I think i've setup everything correctly, here's my github https://github.com/CakeCode123/Cakebot

My problem is that the bot doesn't go online, I've checked the logs and it appears to have a problem but i don't know how to fix it.
[Here are the logs from heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSFU9.png)

Comment: You need to remove the last `discord` in requirements.txt, it's a falsified package. That might be the problem, though I'm not sure. Aside: why are you using 0.14.x? It's fairly out of dated.

Comment: I tried taking off discord, However it still doesn't work. Oh and i actually use 3.6.5 Its 0.14 because probably the one that i looked at was old did not realize it :P

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason to why it didn't work because you had `discord.py==3.5.6`
as your import in the requirements text instead of just `discord.py` or `discord`